# Is it possible to call http request and get response of a website using selenium webdriver java and how?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

how to call http request and get response of 3 websites using selenium webdriver java.if website fails with 403 send an email id to specified email address. and also need to schedule the test

Comment: What You want to do ? Please Explain

Comment: i want to check whether my deployed site is working or not using this. it is not possible to check site manually every day

Comment: You can do this by using java http Post method for your application any rest service if any. and through response you can able to know. There is no way that we can achieve this through selenium

Answer (score 0):

No, It's not possible to get request/response of any of the website. Websites communicate to any specific server for request and response and you are trying to breach security which is not possible.